# Origine dell'espressione "attaccare un bottone a qualcuno"

Tags: phrase-origin

Nel romanzo *La testa perduta di Damasceno Monteiro* di Antonio Tabucchi ho letto:

> «Naturalmente rispose la signorina Odette e gli attaccò un bottone,
>   poveretta, dalla sua sedia a rotelle il suo unico contatto con il
>   mondo era il telefono.»

Ho cercato il significato dell'espressione "attaccare un bottone a qualcuno" e ho trovato che significa obbligarlo ad ascoltare un discorso lungo e noioso. Mi domando, però, quale sia l'origine di questa curiosa espressione.

Comment: Attenzione: attaccar bottone significa semplicemente iniziare una conversazione con qualcuno; se questo _qualcuno_ trova la conversazione lunga e noiosa è discorso a parte, potrebbe invece esser contento che la conversazione sia stata iniziata dall'altro. Tipicamente si usa l'espressione quando una persona (spesso un uomo) tenta i primi passi per _rimorchiare_ un'altra (spesso una donna). Non conosco l'origine ma l'immagine che mi trasmette è quella di un abito che ti si abbottona addosso, e che quindi ti si appiccica addosso e, per toglierlo, devi _sbottonarlo_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un tempo i medici per cauterizzare adoperavano un ferro che all'estremità terminava con una pallottola, simile ad un bottone, a cui si dava fuoco quando lo strumento veniva usato (e veniva detto un bottone di fuoco). Il dolore era acuto, seppur breve. Da cui, fuori dal linguaggio medico con il senso figurato di "parlar male di qualcuno" e poi con ulteriore estensione, nel senso di tormentare con un discorso noioso, molesto. (Fonte: Sandron:  *Dizionario Linguistico*)

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Vedo che si parla [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=HmIJeeKibPEC&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=%22bottone+di+fuoco%22&source=bl&ots=xlR-XPKLuX&sig=fbxq1_Vbdi1GdH3_RkPBjkj6x18&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf6obzzYDZAhUE0RQKHdEQAqIQ6AEIDjAB#v=onepage&q=%22bottone%20di%20fuoco%22&f=false) di questo strumento.

Comment: E ne parla anche il [Tommaseo](http://www.dizionario.org/d/?pageurl=bottone).

Comment: E quello che hai scritto sull'origine di questo modo di dire viene anche spiegato in questo [Vocabolario universale della lingua italiana, edizione eseguita su quella del Tramater di Napoli con giunte e correzioni](https://books.google.es/books?id=d8xjvKTe5lsC&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=%22bottone+di+fuoco%22+attaccare&source=bl&ots=sp4ZeRhNY8&sig=DYDF7SGzbnJWbK_OrBN4eQv_T8Y&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ-8iQ0IDZAhUGWxQKHZZiC2sQ6AEIFzAF#v=onepage&q=%22bottone%20di%20fuoco%22%20attaccare&f=false) del 1847.

Comment: Penso che questa risposta sia quella che provenga dalle fonti più affidabili.

Answer (score 2):

*Attaccare un b. a qualcuno, o attaccare bottone con qualcuno*, trattenerlo con una conversazione lunga e noiosa (v. anche attaccabottoni) (www.treccani.it).

L'origine non è certa.  Secondo la seguente fonte:

[attaccare bottone](http://ogni_occasione.enacademic.com/68/attaccare_bottone):

> - Tediare qualcuno con un discorso lungo e noioso, privo di interesse per lui. Non è nota l'origine della locuzione; **sembra che un tempo volesse dire parlar male di uno. L'immagine suggerita potrebbe anche essere quella del seccatore che, quasi afferrando fisicamente per la giacca il riluttante interlocutore, non lo molla finché non abbia finito di ricucirgli un immaginario bottone.**

Fonte: www.ogni_occasione.enacademic.com, *Dizionario dei Modi di Dire per ogni occasione*, 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Il modo di dire "attaccare bottone" ha generalmente una connotazione [negativa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/attaccabottoni/).

Prova a immaginare di stare fermo in piedi mentre qualcuno ti cuce un bottone sulla giacca che hai addosso: questa persona ti sta molto vicina e ti senti annoiato non vedendo l'ora che il bottone venga cucito per così poi andare via! 
Così chi attacca bottone (l'*attaccabottone*) è una persona che effettivamente ha un modo di approciarsi pedante e noioso nei confronti di chi ha di fronte; l'attaccabottoni è anche quello che trova i momenti meno opportuni per intraprendere un dialogo (o meglio monologo!).

Dalle mie parti si dice anche "*attaccare una pezza*" o "*attaccare pezza*", per esempio: "quella signora mi ha attaccato pezza proprio oggi che avevo fretta!"

Altre fonti:
 http://www.ilpiaceredisaperlo.net/?p=438

UPDATE:

> L’origine di tale espressione va ricercata nel gergo militare durante la Prima Guerra Mondiale. Infatti, durante le snervanti attese in trincea, ai soldati capitava spesso di dover cucire bottoni, attività spesso accompagnata da chiacchiere futili.

http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/B/bottone.shtml

Comment: Interessante l'origine dell'espressione che viene spiegato in http://www.ilpiaceredisaperlo.net/?p=438. Potresti aggiungerlo alla tua risposta?

Comment: @Charo: ho aggiunto la citazione ma non so fino a quanto sia affidabile tale sito, non è un'enciclopedia.

Comment: Hai ragione, ma non sembrano avere fonti veramente affidabili per l'origine di quest'espressione.